# FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place. Bash script on windows

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in datasets/wavs/*.wav; do
    ffmpeg -y -i $i  -ac 1  -ar 22050 -map_metadata -1 -c:v mv -c:a copy $i;
done
```

Can't do nothing with that. How can i fix it? Or how can i change directory for saving results?

Comment: What is the error? Quote your variable `"$i"` not `$i`

Comment: FFmpeg cannot edit existing files in-place. - This is error. It's not my code. But i cant run it.

Comment: How can i write directory to saving the result? I never use bash.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1409894/how-do-i-specify-ffmpeg-video-directory  might help you.

Comment: @Bislan : Why don't you simply put the directory into the argument of the _copy_ parameter, for instance `..... copy /tmp/"$(basename $i)"`?

Answer (score 0):

## You have many issues with your script

1. In `ffmpeg` the input and output files cannot be the same file. The input and output must be different, separate files. Easy solution is to output to a different directory.
2. Don't include a path in your loop unless you want to do more work to deal with the included path in the output. Instead, navigate to `datasets/wavs/` with `cd` then use `for i *.wav; do` in the script
3. There is no encoder named "`mv`". If your input had video you would get the error `Unknown encoder 'mv'`. Remove `-c:v` because WAV files do not have video anyway.
4. `-c:a copy` uses stream copy mode. Like doing a copy and paste. You can't stream copy and modify the audio at the same time. This results in `-ac` and  `-ar` being ignored. Remove `-c:a copy`.
5. Windows does not support Bash (I'm guessing an exception is if you install Windows Subsystem for Linux, but I don't use Windows). Windows supports **batch**.

## tl;dr: just give me the answer to copy and paste

Assuming you have a system that supports Bash:

```
mkdir outputs
for i in *.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -ac 1 -ar 22050 outputs/"$i"; done
```